# C# inheritance declaring instances

Tags: c#, inheritance

Let's say i have a Student class that inherits from Person , what is the differences between those:

```
Student s1 = new Student("Ori");
Person s1 = new Student("Ori");
```

Comment: The former is a `Student`, the latter just a `Person`. You need to cast it to `Student` if you want to be able to use the properties and methods of `Student`.

Comment: Well, the latter *is* a `Student` really...

Comment: @Rawling Don't use `is` (c# keyword) here although it's true but it's also Student. http://i.imgur.com/P8TaOc8.png

Comment: `is` is an english word, apart from a programming language keyword :-)

Comment: @Jcl Yes. I just don't want to confuse the OP more than he is now.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the second object is treated by the compiler as a `Person` and you won't be able to access the methods defined in `Student` for that object unless you cast it back when using it.

The object itself in memory is still a `Student`

Answer (score 0):

With both you have a Student.

- Only with the first you can access properties/functions that belong to Student **AND** Person.
- While the 2nd you can **only** access properties/functions of Person.

If you cast the second to a Student then you can access the Student properties again.